# How to call @Html.RenderAction on HttpPost

Tags: asp.net-mvc, renderaction

Following is the exact structure of a View in my MVC application.

A view contains ->

1. LHS: `@Html.RenderAction`, which invokes an action by supplying some parameters and loads Partial View that is showing a list to the user.
2. RHS: Another PartialView on this view that contains Filter options. So when user clicks on Submit button on this partial view, it should update the list in LHS.

I have completed loading initial list using `@Html.RenderAction`.

Now I want to perform calling `@Html.RenderAction` when user clicks "Submit" button in RHS view. In short, I want to implement 2nd point of my above list.

Any suggestions on this, much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do that (implement 2nd point) with an ajax form, that posts to an action that returns a  partial View for LHS with filtered results. You specify target of that ajax form to be the id of LHS container.

```
@using(Ajax.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "LHSContainer" }))
{
    ...your filtering inputs and submit button...
}
```